# How to clear an Android App's permission to use the authentication credentials of your account?

Tags: android

I can clear data or uninstall the app, but it never again asks for permission. I'm having trouble tracking down a bug because I can only test the bug conditions once per phone. :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about Google account authentication tokens? If so you should be able to revoke them from [This google account link](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens) I found it via the [Google accounts dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/?hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately this link only shows stackoverflow. The auth for android apps with account permissions must go elsewhere.